# How to use preg_replace to remove entire URL up until certain point?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

EDIT: I looked into the duplicate answer and added a '/' to the end of my URL, and still have the same issue.

I am trying to create a function that uses preg_replace to remove everything up until a certain set of characters.

**How it should work:**

```
$url = 'https://vimeo.com/66140585';

function getVimeoId($url) {
     $videoID = preg_replace_function($url);
     return videoID;
}
```

$videoID should be: 66140585

However I'm getting the following error: `Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '#' found`

**My Full Code:**

```
function getVimeoId($url){
    $videoID =  preg_replace("#[&\?].+$#", "", preg_replace("#https://(?:www\.)?vimeo.com", "", $url));
    echo videoID;
}
```

I'm sorry I'm new to PHP string functions and still trying to wrap my head around it...

Comment: As per the error, your `"#https://(?:www\.)?vimeo.com"` has no closing delimiter.

Comment: So adding a delimiter would be preg_replace("#[&\?].+$#", "", preg_replace("#https://(?:www\.)?vimeo.com/", "", $url)); ? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Your 'duplicate' does not help me with my understanding or solution.

Comment: Incidentally, do you know about [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)?

Comment: Why not use pathinfo()?

Comment: @thatemployee Don't use two regex function calls, just use a single `preg_match()` call and be done with it. pattern: https://regex101.com/r/i5BJT6/1  php code: https://3v4l.org/B0As5